# Eclipse option for [only] highlighting “public” “private” “protected”

Tags: eclipse

Can I only highlight access modifier in eclipse? The dark purple highlight thing.

I don't want highlight together with "if", "void", "int" etc.

Comment: I doubt it, they are all keywords.

Answer (score 0):

**No.**
I checked with the current version of Eclipse **Neon**.

Only the keyword "return" is exceptional from others, I don't know Why.

[image]